# How to set a field from multiple field aliases?

Tags: python, pydantic

Is there any way to use multiple field aliases without using a `root_validator`?

My current code is this:

```py
class GetInfo(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(alias='name1')
    name2: str = Field(alias='name2')
    
    @root_validator
    def format_name(cls, values):
        if values['name'] is None:
            if values['name2'] is not None:
                values['name'] = values['name2']
            return values
        return None
```

The `name1` field is sometimes empty while the `name2` field is mostly not empty.
I wanted to use the `name2` value if the `name1` is really empty.

Or can you suggest better way than what I did?

Comment: You mention "empty", but your code validates `None`. Are you confusing `""` with `None`?

Comment: See this branch https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/324

Answer (score 9):

#### Pydantic V1:

Short answer, you are currently restricted to a single alias. (In other words, your field can have 2 "names".) If you want additional aliases, then you will need to employ your workaround.

#### Pydantic V2:

Pydantic V2 introduces ["more powerful alias(es)"](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/fields/#field-aliases):

```
class GetInfo(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(validation_alias=AliasChoices('name1', 'name_1', 'name_one'))
    name2: str = Field(validation_alias=AliasChoices('name2', 'name_2', 'name_two'))


# The following will all be equal
assert all((
    GetInfo(name1="Sam", name2="Colvin"),
    GetInfo(name_1="Sam", name_2="Colvin"),
    GetInfo(name_one="Sam", name_two="Colvin"),
))
```

Comment: it is not working, it seems that aliases parameter has a different behavior. any idea how to do that?

Comment: you just stole my answer.

Answer (score 4):

if anyone is wondering, here is a working solution with pydantic v2

```
import pydantic
print(pydantic.__version__ )  # 2.1.0 
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, AliasChoices
class User(BaseModel):
    first_name: str = Field(validation_alias=AliasChoices('first_name', 'fname'))
print(User(first_name="Sam"))
print(User(fname="toto"))
```